# Join multiple values into same cell R

Tags: r, dataframe, spacy, part-of-speech

I have a data frame with pos values for each document split down into single tokens. How can I merge the individual pos values into one single cell separated by a comma?
So now I have something like

```
  doc_id sentence_id token_id    token  pos entity
1  text1           1        1   xxxxxx PRON       
2  text1           1        2     xxxx  AUX       
3  text1           1        3      xxx  AUX       
4  text1           1        4  xxxxxxx VERB       
5  text2           1        5     xxxx  DET       
6  text2           1        6      xxx NOUN
```

How can I make it into

```
  doc_id                      pos    entity
1  text1  PRON, AUX, AUX, VERB...       
2  text2  AUX, NOUN, PRON, ADJ...       
3  text3  ...
4  text4  ...  
5  text5  ...
6  text6  ...
```

Do I need to create a new data frame or is there a Spacy function that can do this directly?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse it like so:

```
aggregate(pos ~ doc_id, doc_df, paste, collapse = ", ")
```

You can store this in a separate dataframe and merge in any other columns you want to include from the original, or if you just need these two then you can use this directly.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)     
df1 %>%
     group_by(doc_id, entity) %>%
     summarise(pos = toString(pos), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!